# Python2.4 Amiga OS M68K restarting system and where to get libs

Tags: amiga, programming

Just installed python 2.4 on my Amiga os3.9. sometimes when I run a script the machine restarts. Any idea why that may be? It has 030 with MMU, 64MB RAM and 1MB chip ram. All MMU libs are installed. This is the guide I followed:

https://cowboy3398.wordpress.com/2020/05/12/installing-python-2-4-on-amiga/

How to get additional python libs anyway if you can't just PIP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience with python in amiga OS 2.1 was it needed a lot of stack. Perhaps this also works in os3.9? Try increase the stack which back then allowed max 25000 (using the command 'stack 25000').
A larger value for stack on OS3.x is allowed, and depending on your python-script may be needed.

As to the "get additional python libs", I do not see how you can get around compiling.
Any pure-python extension that is 'old enough' has a chance to work by simply copying the python files to the default locations in the python distribution (site-libs) or adding then to the pythonpath.
If the extension you are trying to add uses compiled results you will have to get it to compile (so start from source code) for os3.9 using gcc.
I judge this will be tricky even for those experienced with gcc and python. I have had trouble (symbols, unexpected code tricks) compiling python extensions for python2.6.6 on linux. For amiga os and older python this for sure be worse.
I haven't experience with os3.9, may be easier.

Comment: _"...which back then allowed max 25000"_ - what does this mean? AFAIK the OS 3.1 'stack' command has no such limitation (I tried 'stack 500000' on my OS 3.0 A1200 and it worked as expected).

Comment: "tricky for those experienced with", does this have a missing "not" between 'those' and 'experienced'?

Comment: @Bruce: huge values would block memory for other use. I didn't know the stack could be set that high (I expect the max 25000 value was a very old limit).

Comment: @Vatine: indeed, I meant it would be hard. (thanks)

Comment: _"huge values would block memory for other use"_ - true, but some programs (particularly those ported from other platforms) need it. AmiWolf (a Wolfenstein 3D port by Novacoder) needs at least 300000. Python may be another example of a port that needs a lot of stack.